# Unit testing web service calls

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, junit

I am working on a Java project that is split up into a web project and a back-end project.  The web talks to the back-end via web service calls.

There is one class in the web project that makes all of the web service calls and I would like to add testing around this class.  I want to do unit testing, and not functional testing, so I do not want to have to have the web service actually running to run the tests. If this class were simply passing the calls through to the back-end, I might be willing to overlook testing it, however there is caching happening at this point, so I want to test that it is working correctly.

When the web service is generated jax-ws wsgen it creates an interface that the front end uses.  I have used this generated interface in order to create a fake object for testing.  This works pretty well, but there are issues with this approach.

I am currently the only one on my team that is doing unit testing, and so am the only one maintaining the test code.  I would like to be able to have the test code be built when the rest of the code is built, but if someone else introduces a new method into one of the web service classes, then the interface will have the new method on it, and my fake object will not implement it, and will therefor be broken.

The web and the back end code projects are not dependent on one another, and I do not want to introduce a dependency between them.  So, introducing an interface on top of the web service endpoint does not seem plausible since if I put it in the back-end, my web code needs to reference it, and if I put it in the front-end, my back-end code needs to reference it.  I also cannot extend the endpoint since this will also introduce a dependency between the projects.

I am unfamiliar with how web services work, and how the classes are generated for the web project to be able to refer to them.  So, I do not know how to create an interface in the back end that will be available for me to use in the web project.

So, my question is, how would I get the interface available to my front-end project without introducing a project dependency (in Eclipse build path)?  Or, is there another, better way to fake out the back-end web service that I am calling?

Comment: I think you need to look for `mock-ups` (Mockito, JMockIt) I have not used them too much so I can not give a full answer.

Comment: I am not using any libraries for doing my mocking.  I have generally been mocking by hand (since it is very simple to do, and gives me more control over my mock or fake objects).  Since I am the only developer doing unit testing and trying to get the office to embrace it, I would rather keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: I agree with the recommendation of using a Mocking framework. @Beckyreamy - This actually makes life much simpler than hand-mocking. If you have a 20 method interface, but only want to test one method, then you simply implement that one. Plus, this addresses the concern called out in the original post about additions to interfaces. If the interface is extended, mocking frameworks will handle this for you. If you hand-mock, then compile errors are likely (unless you remember to update the hand mocks in the other project). I have used Mockito quite a bit and it has greatly simplified my tests.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I may have to investigate some of the frameworks

Comment: have a look at this framework http://code.google.com/p/smock/

Comment: Prasanna - I can't tell from what is on the page you linked to, but does Smock require you to have your web service back end up and running?  This is one thing I would like to avoid, since I want these to run as quickly and easily as possible.

Comment: EJK & SJuan76 -  Thanks for the feedback on the mock frameworks.  From what I have read so far, I am not sold on the idea.  I am seeing a lot of comments about brittleness of tests using these frameworks; comments about tests failing when they shouldn't and passing when they shouldn't.  Since I am trying to introduce testing to the company, I do not want things to fail sporadically and have people decide it is not worth the time and effort.

Comment: @Beckyreamy You will spend more time maintaining your mocks if you do them manually. Mocking allows trivial shuffling of implementations. External services are a prime candidate for mocking for a variety of reasons--you're digging yourself a deeper ditch by avoiding it and introducing dependencies that only you are maintaining.

Comment: I have used hand-written mocks for the last 4 years without any issue.  We are able to change out the implementation without much additional work (if you use the mocks correctly, this isn't a problem).  The amount of time it takes to create a mock by hand is very small.  That is not to say that I would be unwilling to use a framework.  I am just not comfortable with the issues I have seen others put forth with the frameworks that are out there right now.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'd break out the caching code into a testable unit that does not directly depend upon the web service calls.

As for the web services, I find it useful to have both functional tests that exercise the web services and other tests that mock out the web services. The functional tests can help you find edge cases that your mocks may miss.

For instance, I'm using Axis2 and generating stubs from the WSDL. For the mocks, I just implement or extend the generated stubs. In our case the real web service is implemented by an outside organization. Probing their web service through exploratory functional tests has revealed some exceptions that needed to be handled that were not apparent by just examining the generated stubs. I used this information to better mock these edge cases.

Comment: I would love to go in and pull the caching out into a separate set of classes.  This is on my list of improvements to the code, however, since I am rather new to the company, there is some resistance to me going in and making major changes like this.

Comment: As for adding functional tests, I would also like to do that.  I just have not gotten around to that part yet.  As I am introducing the whole automated testing thing to the company, I am trying to take it a little slower so as not to confuse the concept of unit testing with functional testing.

Comment: I don't ask permission to make code more testable. It is part of my professional responsibility.

Comment: Paul, I agree that it is part of my professional responsibility to improve the code that I am working on.  This is why I am introducing automated testing to the company.  However, part of that responsibility is considering the other developers on the team.  They are unfamiliar with testing, and some of the patterns that I want to introduce, so rather than trying to make a lot of big changes, I am trying to incrementally improve the code.